# Sonar 3.7 : Unable to execute wih maven

Tags: java, sonarqube

After upgrading to Sonar 3.7, and launching an analysis with maven 3:

```
mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.jdbc.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver -Dsonar.jdbc.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sonar -Dsonar.jdbc.username=sonar -Dsonar.jdbc.password=sonar -Dsonar.host.url=http://localhost/sonar
```

i get this error :

```
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.1:sonar (default-cli) on project X: Can not execute SonarQube analysis: Unable to execute Sonar: Task null does not exist -> [Help 1]
        org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.1:sonar (default-cli) on project X: Can not execute SonarQube analysis
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
            at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
            at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
            at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
            at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
        Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Can not execute SonarQube analysis
            at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.executeMojo(Bootstraper.java:109)
            at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.start(Bootstraper.java:67)
            at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:109)
            at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
            at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
            ... 19 more
        Caused by: org.sonar.runner.impl.RunnerException: Unable to execute Sonar
            at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:91)
            at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.run(BatchLauncher.java:75)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.doExecute(BatchLauncher.java:69)
            at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher.execute(BatchLauncher.java:50)
            at org.sonar.runner.api.EmbeddedRunner.doExecute(EmbeddedRunner.java:102)
            at org.sonar.runner.api.Runner.execute(Runner.java:90)
            at org.sonar.maven.SonarMojo.execute(SonarMojo.java:172)
            at org.codehaus.mojo.sonar.Bootstraper.executeMojo(Bootstraper.java:104)
            ... 23 more
        Caused by: org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Task null does not exist
            at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:78)
            at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:88)
            at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:73)
            at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.executeTask(BootstrapContainer.java:156)
            at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.BootstrapContainer.doAfterStart(BootstrapContainer.java:144)
            at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:88)
            at org.sonar.api.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:73)
            at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.startBatch(Batch.java:92)
            at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.execute(Batch.java:74)
            at org.sonar.runner.batch.IsolatedLauncher.execute(IsolatedLauncher.java:45)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
            at org.sonar.runner.impl.BatchLauncher$1.delegateExecution(BatchLauncher.java:87)
            ... 31 more
        [ERROR]
        [ERROR]
        [ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
        [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Sonar is running on a tomcat instance. The maven version output is:

```
mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 09:44:56+0100)
Maven home: /usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.0.4/libexec
Java version: 1.6.0_51, vendor: Apple Inc.
Java home: /System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home
Default locale: fr_FR, platform encoding: MacRoman
OS name: "mac os x", version: "10.7.5", arch: "x86_64", family: "mac"
```

Comment: can you post details of your pom setup?

Comment: I complete my question. I pass the properties via the command line.

Comment: Why does Sonar run on Tomcat ? I believe it has a build in application server, which runs on port 9000.

Comment: @kocko i have already a tomcat running on this machine, so i deployed sonar on it.

Comment: gontard is correct that sonar can run within tomcat

Answer (score 0):

I think your missing the sonar plugin definition in your pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>sonar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
</plugin>
```

Comment: org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:2.1:sonar is invoked. Adding your conf in the pom.xml will only fix the version to 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

This site [LINK](http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException) can be helpful. Suggested by maven when running into `Mojo execute` issues.

```
[ERROR] For more information about the errors 
 and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
 http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```